# Preventing login without password in WooCommerce customer account just by email verification

Tags: woocommerce

I don't know what it could be, a bug or a system error or anything else that I don't think is interesting and I want to know if there is a solution that prevented this type of login to the user account? (login without password and only with email verification)

For example, it is enough to have the link of one of the successful orders and then enter the email of that order in the email verification page:

```
https://sample.com/checkout/order-received/9236262/?key=wc_order_ol2BCw72G6626&wc_status=success
```

When you are not logged into any account and you go to an address similar to the one above, which is a real order, a link with a field will appear and ask you to either log in or enter the email related to this order and enter its account. Order without a password!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a plugin doing that function?

Comment: @Syntax_Error Honestly, I'm not sure.  
I disabled all plugins and deleted all caches and tested again, the problem was solved!
Is it possible that it is from the Light Speed Cache plugin?